# Deploying a class to production fails because of code coverage

Tags: deployment, code-coverage

I've got a class on my Sandbox plus a test class that tests it.  The test covers 85% af the class code and test execution runs fine on the sandbox.  I've already deployed the test class to to production and when I try to deploy the actual class it fails.  i've been having a few problems in this org because of code coverage, but code coverage before deployment on the live org is 82%.
Yet when I deploy the class it fails.  Does Salesforce not run test classes on the class being deployed?  I thought it would, and therefore deployed my test class first.

Comment: Can you provide the specific error you are getting?

Comment: Additionally, is it possible your production org has slightly different configurations than your sandbox (extra validation rule, workflow rule, etc.) that makes your test class act a little different?

Comment: I'v checked, and I see no workflows that should interfere with this.  No validation rules active on the object, and the tests run fine on the sandbox.

Comment: The validation rule doesn't necessarily have to be on the object you are working with in your class.  All test code in production is run on a deployment, so any new validation rule could be causing errors in some of your test code already present in production.

Comment: I decided that I wouldn't need the class (it was a trigger handler class) since I could just use OnClick Javascript to fulfill the business requirements.  Thanks for the help!